# XSD to Java with JAXB list with duplicated indentation

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, jaxb

I use jaxb2-maven-plugin 1.6 to generate my Java objects for API implemented in a Spring MVC project.

This is my pom.xml jaxb section:

```
<!-- JAXB 2 -->
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>set-additional-system-properties</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <properties>
        <property>
            <name>javax.xml.accessExternalSchema</name>
            <value>file,http</value>
        </property>
    </properties>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>api</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>xjc</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <xjbSources>
        <xjbSource>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/api/api.xjb</xjbSource>
    </xjbSources>
    <sources>
        <source>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/api/api.xsd</source>
    </sources>
    <packageName>com.example.ems.aaa.xsd.api</packageName>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

This is my jaxb global binding :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1"
               xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <jaxb:serializable uid="1"/>
    </jaxb:globalBindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

This is my xsd definitions :

```
<complexType name="UserPrivilege">
<sequence>
    <element name="Id" type="string"></element>
    <element name="Name" type="string"></element>
    <element name="Method" type="string"></element>
    <element name="Path" type="string"></element>
</sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="UserPrivilegeList">
<sequence>
    <element name="Privilege" type="myapi:UserPrivilege" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
</sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="UserRole">
<sequence>
    <element name="Id" type="string"></element>
    <element name="Name" type="string"></element>
    <element name="Privileges" type="myapi:UserPrivilegeList"></element>
</sequence>
</complexType>
```

This is my response instance :

```
<UserRole>
  <id>17b55c53-7328-4444-95e2-648fb5f9de89</id>
  <name>CONFIGURATOR</name>
  <privileges>
    <privilege>
      <privilege>
        <id>b5f7f39a-f87c-4874-9b16-381a5e0613b3</id>
        <name>CONFIG_PUT</name>
        <method>PUT</method>
        <path>/config/**</path>
      </privilege>
      <privilege>
        <id>7045c699-5608-4584-a3d0-41a96b9d7903</id>
        <name>CONFIG_GET</name>
        <method>GET</method>
        <path>/config/**</path>
      </privilege>
    </privilege>
  </privileges>
</UserRole>
```

If you can see the xml duplicated name indentation of list :

```
<privileges>
    <privilege>
      <privilege>
```

Can I prevent it ?

I need to define "UserRole" as a complexType because I use it as element in another sequence of another complexType.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Change your XSD (part of it) to

```
<element name="UserRole">
<complexType >

<sequence>

    <element name="Id" type="string"></element>

    <element name="Name" type="string"></element>

    <element name="Privileges" type="myapi:UserPrivilegeList"></element>

</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
```

The Java testing code might look like

```
public class PrivIlegeTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(UserRole.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();

        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

        UserPrivilege uPriv = new UserPrivilege();
        uPriv.setId("45455-4466");
        uPriv.setMethod("GET");
        uPriv.setName("GET-CONFIG");
        uPriv.setPath("/*");

        UserPrivilege uPriv0 = new UserPrivilege();
        uPriv0.setId("45888-4466");
        uPriv0.setMethod("POST");
        uPriv0.setName("POST-CONFIG");
        uPriv0.setPath("/*");

        UserRole ur = new UserRole();
        ur.setPrivileges(new UserPrivilegeList());
        ur.getPrivileges().getPrivilege().add(uPriv);
        ur.getPrivileges().getPrivilege().add(uPriv0);

        m.marshal(ur, System.out);


    }

}
```

And the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<userRole xmlns="http://www.example.org/Privilege">
    <Privileges>
        <Privilege>
            <Id>45455-4466</Id>
            <Name>GET-CONFIG</Name>
            <Method>GET</Method>
            <Path>/*</Path>
        </Privilege>
        <Privilege>
            <Id>45888-4466</Id>
            <Name>POST-CONFIG</Name>
            <Method>POST</Method>
            <Path>/*</Path>
        </Privilege>
    </Privileges>
</userRole>
```

The Java classes are generated with JAXB 2.2.